# how to plot graph based on attendance

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a csv file that contains the attendance of a few students on particular dates.

Here is my csv file

```
Name,RollNumber,Attendance,Date,Day,Time
student1,1,Present,1/30/2019,Wednesday,12:34:05
student2,2,Present,1/30/2019,Wednesday,12:34:05
student3,3,Present,1/30/2019,Wednesday,12:34:05
student4,4,Present,1/30/2019,Wednesday,12:34:05
student1,1,Absent,1/31/2019,Thursday,23:34:05
student2,2,Present,1/31/2019,Thursday,23:34:05
student3,3,Present,1/31/2019,Thursday,23:34:05
student4,4,Present,1/31/2019,Thursday,12:34:05
student1,1,Present,2/1/2019,Friday,12:34:05
student2,2,Absent,2/1/2019,Friday,12:34:05
student3,3,Absent,2/1/2019,Friday,12:34:05
student4,4,Present,2/1/2019,Friday,12:34:05
student1,1,Absent,2/2/2019,Saturday,12:34:05
student2,2,Absent,2/2/2019,Saturday,12:34:05
student3,3,Absent,2/2/2019,Saturday,12:34:05
student4,4,Absent,2/2/2019,Saturday,12:34:05
```

I want to plot a graph that show the number of students present and absent on each date from the csv file. How do I do this with matplotlib?

Comment: what have you tried so far? there are a ton of articles and videos out there showing this very requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way in my opinion is to work with pandas [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) as follow:

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_csv_filepath_here')

# Create a duplicate of your target value
df['attendance'] = a.Attendance

# Pivot your dataframe
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index=['Date'], columns='Attendance', values='attendance', aggfunc='count')

# Plot it using pandas (barplot is probably what you want)
df_pivot.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: Result I got]

Of course further plot customizations are possible, as well as other methods would achieve the same result